# c++ is_str_empty predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl, functional-programming

```
std::vector<std::wstring> lines;
typedef std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iterator_t;
iterator_t eventLine = std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(), !is_str_empty());
```

how do I define is_str_empty? i don't believe boost supplies it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use mem_fun / mem_fun_ref:

```
iterator_t eventLine = std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
    std::mem_fun_ref(&std::wstring::empty));
```

If you want when the string is NOT empty, then:

```
iterator_t eventLine = std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
    std::not1(std::mem_fun_ref(&std::wstring::empty)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure STL is enough.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

...

iterator_t eventLine = std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
                                 std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<std::wstring>(), L""));
```

Comment: I still like the mem_fun_ref solution better, but this works. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Use boost::lambda and boost::bind and define it as `bind(&std::wstring::size, _1))`

Comment: That will tell you strings which are NOT empty, not strings which ARE empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a functor:

```
struct is_str_empty  {
  bool operator() (const std::wstring& s) const  { return s.empty(); }
};

std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(), is_str_empty());  // NOTE: is_str_empty() instantiates the object using default constructor
```

Note that if you want a negation, you have to change the functor:

```
struct is_str_not_empty  {
  bool operator() (const std::wstring& s) const  { return !s.empty(); }
};
```

Or just use find as suggested by KennyTM.

Answer (score 1):

In c++17 `std::unary_function` is [removed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) and thus also `std::not1` and `std::mem_fun_ref` (not that modern [compilers care much about that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97a9352edc55d442)...).

Using a lambda would be probably the most natural way now, i.e.

```
auto eventLine = std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
                      [](const std::wstring &s){return !s.empty();});
```

In order to keep the structure of @BillyONeal's answer one would have to use [`std::not_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) and [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), i.e.:

```
auto eventLine = std::find_if(lines.begin(), lines.end(),
    std::not_fn(std::mem_fn(&std::wstring::empty)));
```